# Using PHPMailer to send mail with public host but It won't work

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to send an email using PHPMailer with a "Hover" as my hosting service. But I get different errors depending on which port I use (465, 25, 587, or 8025).If I use 465, It says it could not connect to SMTP host. If i use the other 3 it says "SMTP Error: Could not Authenticate". Eventually, I want to have the information from my contact form as the body, and the email address in it as the email, but for now I just want it to work.

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
// These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//Load composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'mail.hover.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'TheYungGrandpa';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'accountpassword';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('emailOner@gmail.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('emailTwo.suboor@gmail.com', 'Talha2');     // Add a recipient           // Name is optional
    $mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
    $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = '!subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'Hey asshole get your shit together <b>in bold!</b>';


    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
?>
```

I got this code from the example on the Github for PHPMailer, and edited it.

Comment: Probably port 465 isn't open. Check it with  [yougetsignal](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) to make sure. The other error is because either username or password is incorrect as it states or smtpsecure is using another encryption or just try smtpauth `false`

Comment: 465 is closed according to yougetsignal, but how do I fix this? Also Is it okay to use smtpauth false because it should be authenticated right? I will check with the hosting service about the username/ password and make sure i use the correct values.

Comment: if you manage the server it would depend which email server you have to open the port, if you don't manage the server, you can't change it.

Comment: So how do I fix this then, if I can't change that? Do I use the other port instead or what should be done?